# Scraping images using simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm playing around with scraping image URLs, however, I can't seem to make it work.

So far, I've just found a test website which contain a teaser image, but it outputs nothing?

I've included the `simple_html_dom.php` file and then tried below code:

```
$afton_deep_link = file_get_html("http://esport.aftonbladet.se/csgo/csgo-tops-cash-betting-in-esports/");
$afton_img = $afton_deep_link->find("//div[@class='teaser-image-wrapper']//a/img", 0)->src;

echo $afton_img . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image tag you're trying to get is inside a span:

[image]

```
$afton_deep_link = file_get_html("http://esport.aftonbladet.se/csgo/csgo-tops-cash-betting-in-esports/");
$afton_img = $afton_deep_link->find("//div[@class='teaser-image-wrapper']/div/span/img", 0)->{'data-default'};
echo $afton_img;
```

As an alternative, css selectors also work:

```
$afton_img = $afton_deep_link->find("div.teaser-image-wrapper div span img", 0)->{'data-default'};
```

Comment: Okay it seem to work, but you need to explain me why i need to use css style selector? it works fine when i wanna get a <p> tag like `$afton_deep_link->find("//div[@class='abPostContent clearfix']/p"`

Comment: @PeterPik my bad, it works just fine, the query needs to be tweaked though, check out me revision

Comment: Okay seem to work now. do you know whether it is possible to get the 672x336 image?